# EF 4.2 Code First -- Image, Location, Product Entities Can't use list

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have product and location entities that may/may not have a collection of images.
I know I cannot create a list in the respective entities, but nor do I want to make an association in the Image entity for the other two.

I just want the Image Entity to have Id and file path.

Is there a way I can do this?

If the answer is I MUST create an association in the Image Entity for the other two, then that means whenever in the future I create a new entity that may/may not have photos, I have to modify the Image entity for the association and I do not like that idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a uni-directional relationship. Is this correct? So you want to access `Collection<Image>` from Product and Location, but not be able to access Product or Location from Image?

You can do this. In EF, the Image class will not have a navigational property to Product or Location -- it will just have Id and FilePath.

However in the database, the Image table ***will*** have columns for ProductId and LocationId. This is so that EF can manage the foreign key relationship and populate the collection propertes on Product and Location.

code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>.HasMany(p => p.Images).WithOptional()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("ProductId"));
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>.HasMany(p => p.Images).WithOptional()
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("LocationId"));
```

When managing these in your application, you can just add images to the Images collection property on your principal entities (Product and Location) without having to set a navigation property from the dependent Image back to the principal (you can't since the foreign key properties are not present).

Answer (score 0):

You could create two new tables, ProductImages and LocationImages, link to the collection from your Product and Locations, when you insert an item for either, insert a record that joins the image and the product.

That way, when you load your product or your location, you can check if there are any association images by checking the collection.